# Wortwahl in "Es würde mich ___ freuen"

Tags: word-choice

> Es würde mich ___ freuen, wenn du mich diesen Sommer besuchen könntest.
>
> (a) sehr
>
> (b) absolut
>
> (c) riesig
>
> (d) unglaublich
>
> (e) durchaus
>
> (f) sehr viel

Passen all diese Worte zum Satz? Ich bin mir besonders nicht sicher mit (e) und (f). Was sind andere Worte, die in diesem Kontext genau passen?

Comment: "Sehr", "riesig", und "unglaublich" drücken ein extrem positives Gefühl aus in diesem Kontext. "Absolut" ebenso, es klingt aber etwas künstlich, finde ich. "Durchaus" hat etwas negatives an sich. "Sehr viel" ist falsch.

Comment: Alle außer (f), wobei (b) komisch klingt und (e) was anderes ausdrückt als (a), (c) und (d). Außerdem passen (g) unheimlich, (h) wahnsinnig, (i) tierisch, (k) mega, (l) hammermäßig, (m) mordsmäßíg, (n) so was von, ... mir gehn die Ideen aus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, that (a) (c) (d) (e) are possible, but I'm pretty sure that (b) is wrong. (f) is by the way totally wrong, we would never say "Es würde mich sehr viel freuen ...". The differences between the correct answers are the following:

- **(a)** this is definitely the most formal way
- **(c)** more informal and a bit stronger than (a)
- **(d)** very informal (never use this in a formal letter for instance) and very strong if not exaggerated
- **(e)** is weaker than (a) and means something slightly different. You could say for instance: "Ich erwarte nicht, dass du mir antwortest, aber es würde mich durchaus freuen." You don't expect someone to do something, but *you wouldn't be "sad"* if he does it anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Let me combine the two comments from above:

(a) "Sehr", (c) "riesig", und (d) "unglaublich" drücken ein extrem positives Gefühl aus in diesem Kontext. (b) "Absolut" ebenso, es klingt aber etwas künstlich. (e) "Durchaus" hat etwas negatives an sich. (f) "Sehr viel" ist etwas komisch und vielleicht sogar falsch.

Außerdem passen (g) unheimlich, (h) wahnsinnig, (i) tierisch, (k) mega, (l) hammermäßig, (m) mordsmäßíg, (n) so was von, ... und noch viele andere.